# Excel Formula to Find a cell that contains a specific text and then copy that cell to another column on the same row

Tags: excel-formula

I am after a strange calculation. My data [image: I have.]

I need a formula or macro in Column G, to search for the Column G heading ("Sales") within Column B to F and copy the cell that contains that text.

So in cell G2, I want to search for "Sales" in B2-F2 and if it finds "Sales" in this range copy the cell that contains it, and if not found on that row just return "None".

This is just sample data and the file I need to get this done is quite large with more than 21000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFNA(INDEX(B2:F2;;MATCH("*"&$G$1&"*";B2:F2;0));"none")
```

[image]

Comment: It is showing an error with the formula? Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: You might need to replace semicolon with comma, depending which region Excel you have

Comment: =IFNA(INDEX(B2:F2,MATCH("*"&$G$1&"*",B2:F2;0)),"none")

Is this look correct? showing the same error though

Comment: Actually, I have managed to get this work now. Yes, I needed to replace them with commas. Thank you very much, saved a lot of my time.